# Available web part width

Tags: web-part, javascript

Is it possible to find out the available web part width in px via JavaScript? Because I need to set the size of a component manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you in the right direction. It's jQuery though.

[jquery.width();](http://api.jquery.com/width/)